# Is there a study that seeks to quantify left/right bias by gender and country?

Tags: ideology, gender, political-spectrum

Here in Russia, women tend to be much more right-wing than men.

Women more often support free market, privatization, vote for billionaires, support the US and NATO policy, support copyright, anti-Communism and other policies associated with the right-wing.

Men are much more patriotic, support big government, protectionism, budget spending, price control, nationalization of key industries and pressure on the oligarchs. They also often express anti-Americanism and oppose NATO bombings worldwide.

Women are also more kin to learn foreign languages and get a profession associated with finances and management while men are likely to work in industry and to study engineering.

So I want to learn what is average distribution of political sympathies between right-wing and left-wing policies by sexes in other countries.

Comment: When you say "vote for billionaires", are you talking about oligarchs who are literally running for Russia's equivalent of parliament, or opposing the prosecution of oligarchs?

Comment: @Anixx - funnily enough, you gave enough exact political details that it's actually a good precise question if you get rid of the words "left" and "right".

Comment: I suspect the difference between men and women, globally, is on the authoritarian scale rather than the economic scale.

Comment: In a press appereance, Hakan Yılmaz, mentioned that women tend to support more propositions that are associated with left, rather than their male counter parts in Turkey. Apparently, no single individual, associates herself with left or right in all the aspects of daily life. His study indicates that people generally tend to be conservative in international relations, "leftist" in public space, and conservative again at their homes in Turkey, which gave me chills because it sounds so much like national-socialism of Third Reich. Link to his talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3UsPEDduYk0

Comment: He gives a lot of numbers and statistics too by the way

Comment: I doubt that this is one such source, but there are many that examine these issues.

Answer (score 10):

In USA (and likely, in the rest of the western countries) the gender gap is decidedly the opposite to what your thesis is for Russia *(though, without details of Russian polls and statistics, I am unsure how much of the data in your question is a personal guess and how much a fact)*.

[The people press](http://www.people-press.org/2012/03/29/the-gender-gap-three-decades-old-as-wide-as-ever/) has reported recent statistics (this is Pew which is typically considered somewhat of a Democrat-biased polling, but the margins are huge enough that the bias won't matter):

[image]

Now, in USA, the really interesting fact is that this huge dis-balance is **entirely** due to unmarried women (I can list speculated reasons, but DA would start screaming that it's a biased answer). From [ABC](http://abcnews.go.com/Politics/OTUS/put-ring-obama-wins-women-married-types/story?id=16057761) in April 2012:

> In February, 64 percent of unmarried women said they would vote for Obama over Mitt Romney, the presumptive Republican nominee, according to a Democracy Corps survey analyzed by Democratic pollsters. Only 31 percent picked the GOP candidate. The gap — 33 points — was 10 points bigger than in it was in January.
>
> Now look at what married women say: 56 percent said they would vote for Romney, and only 37 percent for Obama, with virtually no change from January to February.

Answer (score 1):

The following is not a country-by-country study of the gender gap, but an economic theory of why it exists. http://seekingalpha.com/instablog/399221-tom-au/80964-men-are-stocks-women-are-bonds

In the U.S., the gender gap extends to the "left," and women are more liberal, because they have more options. In traditional societies like Russia, they are more conservative, because their social holdings are more like "bonds," with fewer, but better protected rights, hence more interested in stability than in change.

(I am no expert on politics, but as the published author of [*A Modern Approach to Graham and Dodd Investing*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471584150), have some expertise on stocks and bonds. I also believe in Keynes' dictum that "Practical (wo)men...find themselves the slaves of some defunct economist.")

Comment: First, you should describe what meaning of "liberal" you mean - the American one or the one used in all other countries. In America "liberal" means "left", in other counties it means "right". In Russia women support liberals (in right-wing meaning) and in no way conservative (conservative means left-wing or patriotic in Russia, women are mostly anti-patriotic, pro-West, pro-free-market).

Comment: Full disclosure - both the blog and the book linked are authored by the user who posted the answer :)  Doesn't invalidate the answer in any way, just clarifying that.